# R Shiny checkboxGroupInput - single check boxes to dynamically select multiple data frame columns

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a Shiny page that displays a data frame with an associated check box input that can be used to specify columns to display.

I have managed it successfully with each check box specifying a particular column from the data frame:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput('col_choice'),
    dataTableOutput('my_data')
)

server <- function(input, output){

  my.data <- reactive({
    df <- data.frame('a1' = c(1,2,3),
                     'a2' = c(4,5,6),
                     'b1' = c(1,2,3),
                     'b2' = c(4,5,6),
                     'c1' = c(1,2,3),
                     'c2' = c(4,5,6))
    return(df)
  })
  
  output$my_data <- renderDataTable({
    my.data()[, input$columns, drop = FALSE]
  })
  
  output$col_choice <- renderUI({

    colnames <- names(my.data())
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns:", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       selected = colnames)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

However, I would prefer to set up the check boxes so that each referred to a list of columns.
i.e. one box to select both columns 'a1' and 'a2', one box for both 'b1' and 'b2, one box for both 'c1' and 'c2' rather than a box per column.

Is this possible? Your help is appreciated.

---

To elaborate on the actual implementation... My data frame is quite large. Most columns are grouped and this is reflected in naming with most column names constructed from a variable length character prefix (1-3 letters) followed by variable sequence of digits (some containing underscores) while some columns are identified by name only. Examples include: 'gender', 'sd1', 'sd2_3', 's5', 'hit9'.

I am hoping to figure out a solution in which the checkboxes are labelled by either the prefix or the actual name where appropriate and selection of say the 'sd' checkbox toggles visibility of all 'sd' prefixed columns in the data frame output.

I have attempted (unsuccessfully) to define the list of columns elsewhere to be called in `choices` argument for checkboxGroupInput`:

```
options <- list('SD' = c('sd1','sd2','sd3'),
                'S' = c('s1', 's2', 's3_2'),
                'gender')

output$col_choice <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns:", 
                       choices  = options)
  })
```

While this results in the checkbox labels rendering correctly, selecting the checkbox doesn't call each item in the associated list but rather: `[1] "list(sd1 = \"sd1\", sd2 = \"sd2\", sd3 = \"sd3\")"`

---

Partial success

```
options <- list('SD' = c('sd1','sd2','sd3'),
                'S' = c('s1', 's2', 's3_2'),
                'gender')

output$col_choice <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns:", 
                       choices  = names(options))
  })

  output$my_data <- renderDataTable({
    my.data()[, options[[input$columns]], drop = FALSE]
  })
```

The above functions in so far as I only want one subgroup of columns displayed. However, selecting multiple checkbox options results in `Error: subscript out of bounds`. Close but not quite!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of manual work typing in the column names but it can be simplified/automated depending on your use-case:

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput('col_choice'),
    dataTableOutput('my_data')
)

server <- function(input, output){

  my.data <- reactive({
    df <- data.frame('a1' = c(1,2,3),
                     'a2' = c(4,5,6),
                     'b1' = c(1,2,3),
                     'b2' = c(4,5,6),
                     'c1' = c(1,2,3),
                     'c2' = c(4,5,6))
    return(df)
  })
  
  output$my_data <- renderDataTable({
    # don't proceed unless there are some selected columns:
    req(input$columns)

    # ---
    # if sequence is definite, say your columns are
    # a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2 then:
    # cols <- c(outer(input$columns, 1:2, paste0))
    # ---

    # ---
    # if you need to grep column names starting with a certain prefix:
    first_n_chrs <- substr(colnames(my.data()), start = 1, stop = 1)
    # you can change `start` and `stop` to suit you
    cols <- colnames(my.data())[first_n_chrs %in% input$columns]
    # ---

    # now select `cols`:
    my.data()[, cols, drop = FALSE]
  })
  
  output$col_choice <- renderUI({
    choices <- c("a", "b", "c")

    checkboxGroupInput(
        "columns", 
        "Choose columns:", 
        choices  = choices, 
        selected = choices
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! However, given the size of the actual data frame I'll be working with, this solution isn't totally practical. Manually typing in the column names would ideally be avoided and also displaying the actual column names next to the check boxes isn't possible. In the toy example. How could I have the checkboxes labelled as A, B, C but each refer to the relevant two columns? If I understand your solution correctly the column indexes are defined by splitting the strings manually input to renderUI?

Comment: Is anything like the following possible? ```choices <- c('A' = c('a1','a2'), 'B' = c('b1','b2'), 'C' = c('c1','c2'))``` I have experimented with this but the above still displays 6 checkboxes labelled A1, A2, etc.

Comment: Ahaa, okaay... Are the column names in your real `data.frames` in a sort of a sequence? Like a1, a2, b1, b2 etc

Comment: To a certain extent they are. For example, one sequence of columns all begin with 'sd' followed by a range of digits: 'sd1', 'sd2', 'sd5_1', 'sd5_2'. Not all sequences are complete and sequential though. I had hoped that some like  `'sd' = c(names(df[, grepl('sd', names(df))])` might work?

Comment: Try my edited solution(s)

Comment: Many thanks for your continued help. Your solution involving `first_n_chrs` *almost* achieves my aim.  However, the prefixes for the colnames in my data are of variable length but it seems this solution only functions when prefixes are the same length? i.e. Setting `stop` in `substr` to 2 means the selection for 2 chr prefixes function but those shorter or longer do not.

Comment: To elaborate further, prefixes vary from a single letter to 3 letters long. Other columns have no prefix and are indexed simply by name. An ideal solution would, for example, enable the checkbox labels: 'gender', 'sd', 's' select the gender column, sd prefixed columns and s prefixed columns respectively.

Comment: Edited original post to reflect actual implementation beyond example case provided.